Is regression on aggregated continuous independent variable adequate?
I´m trying to analyze some cohorts that reported aggregate data (mean, SD, and n) of a physiological parameter for the outcome of interest, which is a nominal variable but fairly lineal with the dependent variable.
My question is, Is a (weighted?) linear regression of this aggregate date a reliable estimator of an individual-patient data regression?
What would you do in this case


Parameter media (SD represented by size) by outcome, for several cohorts



Individual-Patient data available for an specific cohort


If you have the individual patient data, as the second figure suggests, then this is inefficient, and you should instead consider using something like a mixed model or GEE.

I only have Individual Patient Data for one cohort
